# PHP Socket connection

Tags: php, sockets, browser, terminal, websocket

I have written the following code using Unix Socket. I am able to get the content from the server. When I am execute the below code in the terminal I am able to print the content. But if I execute the code in the browser it is not printing anything.

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_connect($socket, "/tmp/Log");
$msg = 'QUEUE_STATUS$=$abcd';
socket_write($socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
$res = socket_read($socket,100000);
echo $res;
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script and see if error or warning comes up.

Comment: I have added the above function in the top. I didn't get any error.

Comment: @muruga also add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Check error log, sockets may be reacting different on presentation layer.